# Getting 500 internal server error while using curl

Tags: php, curl

I am using two curl for autosuggest and fetching records.when i tested the same code on local its working fine but when i take it live gets 500 intenal server please look into this.

```
switch ($cases){
case 'city' :
    $obj_biz_tmp_info= new info($db_server['CITY']);
    $response_list = $obj_biz_tmp_info->getCity($string);
    $obj_biz_tmp_info->close();
    break;

case 'what' :
    if ($_GET['search'] == "") return false;

    $areasrch = $_GET['search'];

    if(!empty($areasrch)){
        $apiurl = 'http://192.168.1.97/auto.php?search='.urlencode(trim($areasrch)).'&city='.urlencode(trim($city)).'&stp=0&dtres=20&srch_type=2';
        $ch = curl_init($apiurl);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "abcd");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
        $getResults = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        $getResults = json_decode($getResults,true);

        echo json_encode($getResults);      
        //print_r($getResults);

        break;
    }

case 'compsearch':

    if ($_GET['search'] == "") return false;

    $areasrch1 = $_GET['search'];

    if(!empty($areasrch1)){
        $apiurl = 'http://192.168.1.97/auto.php?search='.urlencode(trim($areasrch1)).'&city='.urlencode(trim($city)).'&stp=0&dtres=20&srch_type=2';

        $ch = curl_init($apiurl);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "abcd");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
        $getResults1 = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        $getResults1 = json_decode($getResults1,true);
        echo json_encode($getResults1);

        //print_r($getResults1);

        break;
    }
```

Comment: please, format your `code` properly!

Answer (score 0):

`http://192.168.1.97` is an address on your **local** network, which is probably not accessible from your server.

If the `auto.php` script is hosted on the same server, you can change this:

```
$apiurl = 'http://192.168.1.97/auto.php?search=' // rest of line ommited
```

to

```
$apiurl = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/auto.php?search=' // rest of line ommited
```

Comment: thank u for your reply but its not hosted on same server

Comment: The server (presumably hosted somewhere on the internet) cannot access `http://192.168.1.97` because it's on your local network. So you need to also upload the `auto.php` script to a server and change `http://192.168.1.97` to the address of that server. (Or upload `auto.php` to the same server that you host your code on and do the above)